# How to use the replacements in JAutoDoc plugin for eclipse

Tags: eclipse-plugin, jautodoc

I can't seem to understand how to make the replacements work?

help

Answer (score 1):

I'd ask for clarification in a comment but I don't have enough reputation yet.

**If the problem is that you don't understand what they do:**

Replacements are what JAutodoc uses to create generic comments based on things like method and parameter names.  That's why it can create the comment "Sets the number of questions" above a method called setNumberOfQuestions().

**If the problem is that you're having trouble creating custom replacements:**

Go to Eclipse Preferences > Java > JAutodoc.  There will be a list of the default replacements at the bottom of the window.  You can see from there what format to use when you create your own.  For example, the default ability to comment "Adds the customer" for a method called addCustomer() is reflected in the list with Shortcut: add; Replacement: Adds the; Scope: method; Replace: Prefix.  So let's say you often write methods with names like initializeCustomerList() or initializeArray() and you want JAutodoc to be able to automatically comment those.  You would click the Add button next to the list of current replacements and fill in the fields as follows:

Shortcut: initialize

Replacement: Initializes the

Scope: method

Replace: prefix

Similarly, if you want to teach it about common names you use for fields, you would choose the scope "field" instead of "method".  Or if you use the same names for both fields and methods you could choose "both".